# My Web project is returning this error: Target class [App\Http\Admin] does not exist. I am using laravel 9 to create this project

Tags: php, laravel-9

here are my routes,the first route is for the welcome page, and the second route is for the dashboard. The dashboard has a link which leads to the admin page and when i click it it returns this error: Target class [App\Http\Admin] does not exist.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');   

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');
    Route::patch('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
    Route::delete('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'destroy'])->name('profile.destroy');
});

Route::middleware(['auth', 'admin'])->name('admin.')->prefix('admin')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', [AdminController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
}); 

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

this is my AdminController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.index');
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any `use` statements at the top of your web.php? Is it complaining about the controller or the middleware?

Comment: Yes i have used the use statemements at the top of my web.php. It is complaining about the controller.